# Getting 503 errors when running apt-get update. Curl works fine

Tags: apt

I have been trying to get apt-get update to work for an out of the box Ubuntu 20.04 image built with the 20.04 LTS ISO from Ubuntu. I keep getting 503s for the various URLs, but curl works just fine to them (200's). I'm not behind a proxy and the firewall doesn't appear to be a problem since curl works. I've taken some tcpdump's to show what is taking place which I've shown below. Is there something I missed?

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Curl works just fine:

I had to leave http out as I couldn't post more than 8 links here, but it was there in the curl command I actually ran.

curl us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease

... output omitted

**tcpdumps**

Curl:

```
10.10.9.77.36902 > 91.189.91.81.80: Flags [P.], cksum 0x826f (incorrect -> 0x1566), seq 1:114, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3647906169 ecr 2825603914], length 113: HTTP, length: 113
        GET /ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease HTTP/1.1
        Host: in.archive.ubuntu.com
        User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
        Accept: */*

 91.189.91.81.80 > 10.10.9.77.36902: Flags [.], cksum 0x864a (correct), seq 1:1371, ack 114, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 2825603964 ecr 3647906169], length 1370: HTTP, length: 1370
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2023 14:21:54 GMT
        Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
        Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 17:34:17 GMT
        ETag: "40abc-5a3f8a877d7a3"
        Accept-Ranges: bytes
        Content-Length: 264892
        Cache-Control: max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, s-maxage=3300
        Expires: Thu, 26 Oct 2023 14:21:54 GMT
```

apt-get:

```
10.10.9.77.40174 > 91.189.91.38.80: Flags [P.], cksum 0x82b3 (incorrect -> 0x0190), seq 1:225, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1453901342 ecr 2918323520], length 224: HTTP, length: 224
        GET /ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease HTTP/1.1
        Host: us.archive.ubuntu.com
        Cache-Control: max-age=0
        Accept: text/*
        If-Modified-Since: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 17:34:17 GMT
        User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (2.0.9) non-interactive

10:13:09.797156 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 61, id 12836, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 1416)
    91.189.91.38.80 > 10.10.9.77.40174: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1f11 (correct), seq 1:1377, ack 225, win 502, length 1376: HTTP, length: 1376
        HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
        Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
        Content-Length: 2241
        Connection: close
        P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
        Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
        Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
        Pragma: no-cache
```

Comment: Turns out this was a firewall issue. The Palo's were allowing curl, but not the apt-get. I was able to get around it by temporarily changing the User-Agent by creating a file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/<some file> and put the following in:

Acquire
{
  http::User-Agent "curl/7.68.0";
};

The firewall will be updated as well to allow apt-get. Just thought I would share if someone else has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This was a firewall issue, sorry I didn't get this figured out before I posted. Maybe this post will be helpful for someone that runs into the same issue. Thanks all!